# Interpreting Sphero 16-bit values (such as in Collisions)

Tags: javascript, sphero-api, sphero

I'm using [Cylon.js](http://cylonjs.com/) and Node.js to work with a Sphero, and I'm not sure how I am supposed to reconstruct the 16 bit values from the data returned from a collision event.

The docs imply that they should be signed 16-bit integers, and that the numbers come in (MSB, LSB) byte order, but I get oddball values when I attempt to convert two bytes into what should be negative power ratings (such as impacts from behind or from the left).

The Javascript code I am using to convert a two-btye Sphero value is this:

```
  function convertToSignedInt(msb, lsb) {
    var negative = msb > 128;
    if (negative) {
      msb -= 128;
    }
    var value = msb*256 + lsb;
    if (negative) {
      value = 0 - value;
    }
    return value;
  }
```

Given raw collision data like the following:

```
{"SOP1":255,"SOP2":254,"ID_CODE":7,"DLEN":17,"DATA":[18,31,255,104,0,0,1,0,67,0,6,0,0,9,1,95],"CHK":156}
```

I then attempt to convert the DATA property to a more readable object using this:

```
  function convertCollisionData(data) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.xPower = convertToSignedInt(data[0], data[1]);
    obj.yPower = convertToSignedInt(data[2], data[3]);
    obj.zPower = convertToSignedInt(data[4], data[5]);
    obj.impactAxis = data[6];
    obj.xImpact = convertToSignedInt(data[7], data[8]);
    obj.yImpact = convertToSignedInt(data[9], data[10]);
    obj.speed = data[11];

    return obj;
  }
```

To come up with this:

```
{"xPower":4639,"yPower":-32616,"zPower":0
    ,"impactAxis":1,"xImpact":67,"yImpact":6,"speed":0}
```

It's obvious that the yPower is completely wrong, since this was a right-side (positive X) collision.  Since the xImpact and yImpact values are positive, they appear to be converting correctly.

So the short version of the question is, **what is the proper way to convert the two bytes to a signed integer?**

Comment: Are you sure they are in big-endian order? If they are, `yPower` should be negative if I'm not wrong (but not the value in your code).

Comment: Instead of the code you've got, I'd just combine the bytes (in the proper order, as @Qantas94Heavy points out), left-shift by 16, and then right-shift by 16. The right-shift operator does sign extension. If `[255, 104]` is really a big-endian pair, the value is `-152`.

Comment: Also, is "DATA" an array or a buffer? If it's a buffer, you could just use `readInt16BE`. I ask this as some of the issues on Github show them as buffers, but I'm not too familiar with the project itself.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Thanks for the tips.  yPower is not negative because it is a raw rating of power, not direction.  It's supposed to be positive in all cases, to the best of my understanding.

Comment: Well if the values *are* big-endian, then `255, 104` must be negative. If they're little-endian, then the value is `26879`, which seems big (but maybe not?).